# GraphQL Mongoose: Cast to ObjectId failed for value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I have the following resolver for GraphQL:

```
const Post = require("../../models/Post");

module.exports = {
  getAllActivePosts: async (userId) => {
    try {
      const posts = await Post.find({
        userId: userId
      })
        .select(["name", "createdAt"])
        .populate("posts", ["name", "createdAt"]);

      return posts;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    }
  },
};
```

which tries to get all active posts by the ID of the user from the Post model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  }
});

module.exports = Post = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

Here's the GraphQL Schema:

const { buildSchema } = require('graphql');

```
module.exports = buildSchema(`
        type User {
            _id: MongoId!
            email: String!
            password: String
        }

        type Post {
            _id: MongoId!
            userId: MongoId!
            content: String!
            createdAt: String!
        }

        scalar MongoId

        input LoginInput {
            email: String!
            password: String!
        }

        type RootQuery {
            login(email: String!, password: String!): AuthData!
            getAllActivePosts(userId: MongoId!): [Post]
        }

        type RootMutation {
            createUser(loginInput: LoginInput): AuthData!
        }

        schema {
            query: RootQuery
            mutation: RootMutation
        }
    `);
```

... and the GraphQL query I'm running in GraphiQL:

```
{
  getAllActivePosts(userId: "5fbfc92312b90071179a160f") {
    name
    createdAt
  }
}
```

For this, the result of the query is:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ userId: '5fbfc92312b90071179a160f' }\" at path \"userId\" for model \"Post\"",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "getAllActivePosts"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "getAllActivePosts": null
  }
}
```

Searched here for similar issues, tried wrapping `userId` in `ObjectId`, but nothing helped. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I was go through this problem once a year ago with no solution till i get main concept of graphql.
Here you are passing string

```
{
  getAllActivePosts(userId: "5fbfc92312b90071179a160f") {
    name
    createdAt
  }
}
```

and graphql expecting to have `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`

```
getAllActivePosts(userId: MongoId!): [Post]
```

You need to do sync like

```
 getAllActivePosts(userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5fbfc92312b90071179a160f")) {
```

But using above way you are not eligible for run query in graphiQL becuse there is no mongoose defined.

```
type RootQuery {
    login(email: String!, password: String!): AuthData!
    getAllActivePosts(userId: String!): [Post]
}
```

Better solution is use userId input as string and then validate on your resolver function like

```
getAllActivePosts: async ({ userId }) => {
    try {
      if(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(userId)) {
        const posts = await Post.find({
          userId: userId
        }) 
        .select(["name", "createdAt"])
        .populate("posts", ["name", "createdAt"]);
       // you can;t return null you need to return array
       return posts ? posts : []
      } else {
       // if mongoose id is wrong
       return []
      }
   } catch(error) {
    // it is better to throw error return blank array to complete flow
    throw error
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that, mentioned in the post. It didn't help.

Comment: did you do this in query ``getAllActivePosts(userId: String!): [Post]`` becuse i have working code of it. thanks

Comment: Thanks, I found the resolution and answered below. Thanks for the String!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, I was using `userId` directly, whereas I should've used `args.userId`. The proper resolver below:

```
module.exports = {
  getAllActivePosts: async (args) => {
    try {
      const posts = await Post.find({
        userId: args.userId
      })
        .select(["name", "createdAt"])
        .populate("posts", ["name", "createdAt"]);

      return posts;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    }
  },
};
```

and for the schema:

```
getAllActivePosts(userId: String!): [Post]
```

Comment: ```async ({ userId }) => {``` use destructuring assignment